# How to convert certain categorical values from a DataFrame to numerical(int) in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, converters

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and categorical data in it which I want to assign a numerical (int) value in order to proceed with the data clean-up I need to do.

e.g. I want the cells in the column OldValue & NewValue containing "1st Call" to have a value of 2, "2nd Call" to have a value of 3, and so on...

I post a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9T4w.png) of my dataframe so you understand what I mean.

I am new to programming languages hence if you could please put a practical example to your answer it would be of huge help.

Comment: Please don't post images to share sample data. Instead, copy and paste your data in text format and use code formatting to format it as a table. Also please show the desired output in the same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and passing a dictinary which maps each category on a numerical value and then add the new column to your DataFrame:

```
df['OldValueInt'] = df['OldValue'].replace( {'1st Call attempted': 2, '2nd Call attempted': 3})
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','x'],['b','x'],['a','y']], columns=['ab','xy'])

df['abInt'] = df['ab'].replace('a': 1, 'b': 2)

print df
```

which yields

```
  ab xy  abInt
0  a  x      1
1  b  x      2
2  a  y      1
```

or if you want to replace multiple columns:

```
df[['ab','xy']] = df.replace( {'ab': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 
                               'xy': {'x': 2, 'y': 3}} )
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it was really helpful and easy!